# Prove that $\int 1/x\, \text{d}x=\ln |x|$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

What is the proof that $$\int \frac{1}{x}\, \text{d}x=\ln |x|?$$

Please note that similar questions refer to $\ln x$, and not $\ln |x|$ as I have seen in Calculus textbooks.

---

Given the formula that $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\ln x=\frac{1}{x},$$ it is obvious that for $x>0$, $\int 1/x\, \text{d}x=\ln x$; however I am unsure how the above definition is proven over all $x\neq 0$.

Comment: For $x>0$, an elementary  definition of $\ln x$ is that it is $\displaystyle\int_1^x\frac{\mathrm dt}t$. If $x<0$, use the substitution $x=-y$.

Comment: If you want to prove the formula from first principles, you need to give the *definition* of $\ln x$. There are different ways to define it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On $(0,\infty)$, we have $\log|x|=\log x$ and, as you know, $\log'(x)=\frac1x$.

And, on $(-\infty,0)$, $\log|x|=\log(-x)$ and, by the chain rule, if you differentiate $\log(-x)$, you get $-\frac1{-x}$, which is equal to $\frac1x$.

Answer (score 4):

When $x\lt 0$, $\ln |x|=\ln(-x)$, but then:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(-x)=\frac{1}{-x}\frac{d}{dx}(-x)=\frac{1}{-x}(-1)=\frac{1}{x}$$

so $\ln|x|$ is the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\lt 0$ too.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the easiest solution is to show that $\frac{d}{dx} \ln \lvert x \rvert = \frac{1}{x}$, and since you know that $\ln(x) = \ln \lvert x \rvert$ for $x >0$ you can treat this as an extension of the "normal" natural logarithm.

You can do this by using that $\lvert x \rvert = \sqrt{x^2}$ and using the chain rule. You get
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} \ln \lvert x \rvert & = \frac{d}{dx} \ln \left( \sqrt{x^2}\right)\\
& = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{x^2}}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}  \sqrt{x^2}\\
& = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{x^2}}\cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2}}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}  x^2\\
& = \frac{1}{ \color{purple}{\sqrt{x^2}}}\cdot \frac{1}{\color{blue}{2}\color{purple}{\sqrt{x^2}}} \cdot \color{blue}{2}x\\
& = \frac{1}{\color{purple}{x^2}} \cdot x\\
&= \frac{1}{x}
\end{align*}

Comment: This is a circular argument, in the second line you use the derivative so you are already assuming your statement to be true,

Comment: @HenryLee, I used the fact that for positive arguments $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, as is stated by the OP in the post. Clearly $\sqrt{x^2}>0$, so on the second line I'm using nothing circular.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\ln|x|$$
$$e^y=|x|$$
$$e^y\frac{dy}{dx}=\operatorname{sgn}(x)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(x)}{|x|}=\frac1x$$
where the exponential function:
$$e^y=\exp(y)$$
is defined as the function satisfying the following statements:
$$f(x)=\exp(x),\,f^{-1}(x)=\ln(x)$$
$$f'=f$$

Answer (score 0):

An "indefinite integral" formula of the form
$$
\int f(x)\,dx=F(x)+C\tag{1}
$$
is understood as $F$ is an antiderivative *on some (open) interval $I$*, i.e., $F'(x)=f(x)$ for every $x\in I$. When the context is clear, one usually write (1) without mentioning explicitly the interval $I$.

The formula
$$
\int \frac{1}{x}\,dx=\ln|x|+C
$$
is understood valid for any (open) interval $I$ *not containing $0$*.

The natural logarithm function $\ln x$ is defined only for $x>0$. It does not make sense to prove
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x},\quad x<0
$$
since the left hand side is undefined.

However, one can prove that for $x<0$,

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln(|x|)=\frac{1}{x}\tag{2}
$$

You can prove (2) using the chain rule if you allow to use the fact $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$.

If you want to prove (2) from first principles, then you need to give the *definition* for the logarithm.