# When do the functions have the same slope?

Tags: calculus

I recently came across the following:"Consider $f(x) = 3x^2 + 14x -1$ and $g(x) = -4\ln{x}$, where do the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same slope?"

My answer to this was as follows: We would like to compute $f'$ and $g'$, so we have the the following $f' = 6x + 14$ and $g' = -\frac{4}{x}$. Now $f'(x) = g'(x)$ so $6x + 14 = -\frac{4}{x} \implies 6x^2 + 14x + 4 = 0$, this factors into $(x+2)(6x+2)$ both of which yield negative $x$ values. Now the natural log isn't defined for negative $x$, so is the answer there exists no such points?

Thank you!

Comment: Your solution seems fine.

Comment: Looks good. The trap is that some students will not see that $x$ cannot be negative.

Comment: Indeed, in hindsight we could just remark that $g(x)$ is decreasing throughout its domain $(0,\infty)$, while $f(x)$ is increasing throughout $(0,\infty)$, and so the two graphs can never have the same slope.

Comment: Just as a comment, you [can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3987028/695196) that $\frac{d}{dx} \ln|x| = \frac{1}{x}$, and since it has the same derivative as $\frac{1}{x}$ you can take $\ln|x|$ to be an extension of the logarithm into the negatives. So although $g$ doesn't share slope with $f$, the function $-4\ln|x|$ does!